# finding a pair with given sum in BST

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

// Stack type 

struct Stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    struct node* *array;
};

struct Stack* createStack(int size)
{
    struct Stack* stack =
        (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->size = size;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array =
        (struct node**) malloc(stack->size * sizeof(struct node*));
    return stack;
}
```

What does this statement do?

```
stack->array =
    (struct node**) malloc(stack->size * sizeof(struct node*));
```

What will be the memory representation of it?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc let us know what is unclear in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
stack->array =
 (struct node**) malloc(stack->size * sizeof(struct node*));
```

struct node** returns a pointer to a pointer (to the stack)

stack->size is the amount of items of the stack
sizeof(struct node*) is the size of a pointer to a node.

So it creates an array of pointers, where each pointer points to one element within the stack.

Comment: so i guess this wiil be like :-

Answer (score 0):

The above statement allocates space for an array of `struct node *`, i.e. pointers to `struct node`.

Each pointer in this array can then point to an instance of `struct node`.